# How to Stop MySQL for Excel Add-In From Making Changes to 'FUNCRES.XLAM'?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mysql

Each time I use the "Mysql for Excel" add-in, and then want to close MS Excel 2010, I am prompted with the following:

"Want to save your changes to 'FUNCRES.XLAM'?"

Is there a setting or way to disable the add-in from making changes to this file?

As is, I have to close any file I'm working on twice, and then close the program   to bypass the prompt. Annoying.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's not an error, but it's a usual procedure Excel follows when you close the Workbook which has attached with MYSql Addin.

Reason is simple when you use the Addin, you connect to Databases, so that Excel prompts you to SAVE the changes to the Workbook before you Close it.

As soon as you respond the Message appears, will clear the connections with Databases.

*Remember, if you doesn't follow this you may loose the Database connections next time when you load the Workbook.*

Comment: Thx. It does seem to be normal behavior; i.e., when a file is changed (even by an add-in) MS Excel will prompt the user to save changes.  But, this is relatively new behavior with this particular add-in.  I've been using it for years, and within the past few months it has systematically started to prompt me to save changes to the FUNCRES.XLAM file.  I am not making the change to this file ... it must be the add-in.

Comment: Yes you are write, FUNCRES.XLAM & ATPVBAEN.XLAM are two Add Ins part of Analysis Tool  Pack. Possibly at some point you have used any Analytical features, while connecting MySql Database. I can suggest two steps. 1. Uncheck the Analysis Tool Pack  2. Use Save as to convert FUNCRES to a normal file, then just close all code windows and hit Save as add-in if still open, to get rid of that problem. I do hope this help you.